# Best strategy for migrating mysql enums to doctrine entities with symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am currently in the process of migrating a legacy app over to symfony2, the problem is that I have a lot of mysql enum columns, I know that doctrine does not support enum data types and that one workaround is to store as a string but I would really lose the ability to properly sort the data because varchars are a lot slower, I do have a lot of tables with the enum data types and modifying the schema would be really hard, what are my options?? What can you suggest that will make a transition to symfony2 a lot smoother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solution

- **Solution 1:** Mapping to Varchars
- **Solution 2:** Defining a Type

for more information please consult this link: [Mysql Enums doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/cookbook/mysql-enums.html)

Comment: Solution 1 is out of the question because it will make the database a lot slower. Solution 2, I will have to create many classes for each unique enum, is there a way of creating just ONE type class for the enum and pass as arguments the options needed from within the entity definitions??

Comment: I do not think there is any other solution for now :(

Comment: Well that certainly throws a wet blanket on my plans! I may end up going with solution 2 but It will be a slow process, thank you a.aitboudad!

Answer (score 3):

Try this it worked for me

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#reference-dbal-configuration

in the app/config/config.yml file add

```
    mapping_types:
       enum: string
```

e.g below

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    charset:  UTF8
    mapping_types:
        enum: string
```

then you can use e.g.

```
@ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('A', 'B')")
```